# add new buttons dynamically into DataTable jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I've successfully implemented create button, and it creates OK into my datatable, but I don't know how to insert buttons in that new row. Please see picture:
[image]

Note: I have hidden column ID.
Here is my JS:

```
$('.button14').click(function () {

        $.ajax({
            url: "/AdeccoViews/CreateAdeccoView",
            contentType: 'application/json;',
            data: JSON.stringify({ date: document.getElementById('datepickerCreateModal').value, client: $('#Client :selected').val(), eventType: $('#Event :selected').val() }),
            //data: JSON.stringify({ id: t.row('.selected').data()[0] }),//pravi kod
            type: 'POST',
            success: function (result) {
                if (result.id > 0) {t.row.add([
                            result.id,
                            document.getElementById('datepickerCreateModal').value,
                            $('#Client :selected').text(),
                             $('#Event :selected').text(),
                             result.name,
                             'buttonEdit, buttonDelete'@*,
                             '@Html.Raw(@"<button type=""button"" data-id=""65"" class=""btnEdit"" data-toggle=""modal"" data-target=""#modalFirst"">Edit</button>
                <button type=""button"" data-id=""65"" class=""button13"">Delete</button>")'*@
                ]).draw(false);
                }
                $('#modalCreate').modal('toggle');
                swal("Dodato!", "Novi je dodat!", "success");
            },
            error: function (valid) {
                //window.location.href = "/Views/ERROR";
                swal("Došlo je do greške!", "Molimo vas da pokušate ponovo!", "error");
            }
        });
    });
```

edit: `success: function (result) {
                    if (result.id > 0) {t.row.add([
                                result.id,
                                document.getElementById('datepickerCreateModal').value,
                                $('#Client :selected').text(),
                                 $('#Event :selected').text(),
                                 result.name,
                                t.row.add(result)
                                ]).draw(false);
                    }
                    $('#modalCreate').modal('toggle');
                    swal("Dodato!", "Novi je dodat!", "success");
                }`

Comment: Take a look at this function. https://datatables.net/reference/option/createdRow It is used to dinamically build row content when it is added to the table. I don't understand why you are redifining the `add` function. I suggest to re-use the code used for initial table creation. DataTable.add will apply initial settings to the new row

Comment: I didnt understand you..

Comment: If you already have a custom way to dispaly your table and it add the buttons successfully. Just add the new row to the table. `t.row.add(result);` https://datatables.net/reference/api/row.add()

Comment: @TCHdvlp I've put edit in my post, did you mean like this? It doesnt work.

Comment: Nope. `success: function (result) { if(result.id > 0) { t.row.add(result).draw(false); } ... }` Of course, the `result` must be an exact representation of a row as it used for the initial display of the table.